# How can I prove that induced norm of a row-stochastic matrix $A$, with respect to $\lVert \cdot\rVert_{\infty}$ is equal to one.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $A\in[0,1]^{n\times n}$ be a row-stochastic matrix. Then how can I prove that the induced norm of $A$ with respect to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$ is equal to one?

In other words, I have to prove that,
\begin{equation}
\lVert A \rVert_{\infty \rightarrow \infty} = sup \frac{\lVert Ax\rVert_{\infty}}{\lVert x\rVert_{\infty}}=1 
\end{equation}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$\ $\{0\}$.

Comment: Have you written down the inequality/ies you’d need to prove? That would show some effort on your part.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe ; I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Each coordinate of $Ay$ is a convex combination of the coordinates of $y$. So, $\|Ay\|_\infty \leq \|y\|_\infty$ for each $y$.

Then, choosing $y$ with all coordinates equal to some constant $\alpha$, we see that $\|Ay\|_\infty = \|y\|_\infty$ since $A$ is row stochastic. This gives us a lower bound on the supremum.

The first part gives us that $\sup_x \frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty} \leq 1$ while the second part shows that $\sup_x \frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty} \geq 1$. Putting these two inequalities together gives equality.

Comment: If you take $y$  with all coordinates equal to some constant $\alpha$, then you will get $||Ay||_{\infty}=||y||_{\infty}=|\alpha|$.

Comment: Updated my answer